# dcm4che get TAG of value multiplicity (VM) greater than 1

Tags: dicom, dcm4che

My question is somehow simple.

I want to get all the values from a TAG of VM>1.

For example the (0018,1310) tag, named Acquisition Matrix is of VM=4, so it stores 4 values separated by dash like:

```
0/320/192/0
```

I want to read all values stored in this TAG, but if i use:

```
...
acquisitionMatrix = dcmObj.getString(Tag.AcquisitionMatrix);
....
```

i only get the first! How can i achieve this?

Comment: http://www.dcm4che.org/docs/dcm4che2-apidocs/org/dcm4che2/data/DicomObject.html#getStrings(int) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that it can be done as Tarmo suggested... However i managed to get these values as int(s) using:

```
...
int[] matrix = null;
matrix = dcmObj4.getInts(Tag.AcquisitionMatrix);
for(int i=0; i<matrix.length;i++) {
    log.info(">>>>>> Acquisition matrix[" + i + "]: " + matrix[i]);
}
...
```

Comment: That's just a question of what kind of data type You need. Since Your original code used getString, I proposed getStrings. There are singular and plural methods for all datatypes - getInt vs getInts for example. That is all down to what You actually need.